# Count based on number of occurrences - ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed around 30K documents in an ElasticSearch index. Each of these documents has a field called severity, which is an Integer value. These integers can range from 0 to 5, in increments of 1 (0,1,2,3,4,5). I would like to get a count of the number of documents with severity 0, severity 1, severity 2, etc....

I have tried value_count and range, but they both seem to be unsuitable for my purpose.

This is what one of my documents looks like. Some values have been removed, but the essential thing is to aggregate based on severity

```
{
   "_index": "incident_db",
   "_type": "incidents",
   "_source": {
      "incident": {
         "name": "something",
         "severity": 3
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply using a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) like this:

```
POST /incident_db/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "incident.severity"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt realize in my n00bness that I can do a term search in ES.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to immediately do that, but it didnt allow me to. Thanks again