# Count of "actual hits" (not just matching docs) for arbitrary queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

This one really frustrates me. I tried to find a solution for quite a long time, but wherever I try to find questions from people asking for the same, they either want something a little different (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734693/elasticsearch-total-distinct-occurrences-across-whole-data) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324770/count-based-on-number-of-occurrences-elasticsearch) or [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-find-count-of-inner-hits/112761)) or don't get an answer that solves the problem (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083385/elasticsearch-count-number-of-hits-in-each-document)).

**What I need**

I want to know how many hits my search has in total, independently from the type of query used. I am **not** talking about the number of hits you always get from ES, which is the number of documents found for that query, but rather the *number of occurrences of document features matching my query*.
For example, I could have two documents with text a text field "description", both containing the word `hero`, but one of them containing it *twice*.
Like in this minimal example here:

Index mapping:

```
PUT /sample
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 1,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "name": { "type": "keyword" },
                "description": { "type": "text" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Two sample documents:

```
POST /sample/doc
{
    "name": "Jack Beauregard",
    "description": "An aging hero"
}


POST /sample/doc
{
    "name": "Master Splinter",
    "description": "This rat is a hero, a real hero!"
}
```

...and the query:

```
POST /sample/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": { "description": "hero" }
    },
    "_source": false
}
```

... which gives me:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 0.22396864,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "sample",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "hoDsm2oB22SyyA49oDe_",
                "_score": 0.22396864
            },
            {
                "_index": "sample",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "h4Dsm2oB22SyyA49xDf8",
                "_score": 0.22227617
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So there are **two hits** (`"total": 2`), which is correct, because the query matches two documents. **BUT** I want to know many times my query matched *inside each document* (or the sum of this), which would be **3** in this example, because the second document contained the search term *twice*.
**IMPORTANT**: This is just a simple example. But I want this to work for any type of query and any mapping, also nested documents with `inner_hits` and all.
I didn't expect this to be so difficult, because it must be an information ES comes across during search anyway, right? I mean it ranks the documents with *more* hits inside them *higher*, so why can't I get the count of these hits?
I am tempted to call them "inner hits", but that is the name of a different ES feature (see below).

**What I tried / could try (but it's ugly)**

- I could use highlighting (which I do anyway) and try to make the highlighter generate *one* highlight for *each* "inner match" (and don't combine them), then post-process the *complete* set of search results and count *all the highlights* --> Of course, this is *very ugly*, because (1) I don't really want to post-process my results and (2) I'd have to get **all** results to do this by setting `size` to a high enough value, but actually i only want to get the number of results requested by the client. This would be a lot of overhead!
- The feature `inner_hits` sounds very promising, but it just means that you can handle the hits inside nested documents independently to get a highlighting for each of them. I use this for my nested docs already, but it doesn't solve this problem because (1) it persists on inner hit level and (2) I want this to work with non-nested queries, too.

Is there a way to achieve this in a generic way for arbitrary queries? I'd be most thankful for any suggestions. I'm even down for solving it by tinkering with the ranking or using script fields, anything.

Thank's a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely not recommend this for any kind of practical use due to the awful performance, but this data is technically available in the term frequency calculation in the results from the explain API. See [What is Relevance?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) for a conceptual explanation and [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) for usage.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I am aware of TF/IDF - the problem is that I also need this data for nested queries like *"all docs that contain nested fields that have arbitrary features x and y"*. Then I want to know how many nested objects matched in total, so the sum of all nested hits of all total hits. I know that if I post-process my results to get this, it will be a very expensive operation. But maybe there's no other way. I really need this, performance is always important and all, but not too critical in my case.